# Getting rows of a table based on query on another table

Tags: mysql, cross-apply

I have these 2 tables

```
[Products]
ID
CompanyID,
Name,
PartNo,
IDSGroup,
ChartNo

[Company]
ID,
Name,
RegistrationNo,
RegistrationDate
```

I want to show these columns from tables when user search for a company name:

```
Company.Name, Product.Name, Product.PartNo, Product.IDSGroup
```

This search query let me get the CompanyID

```
Select Company.ID from Company WHERE Company.Name LIKE "$userSearch%"
```

Now I want to use Company.ID for this query to get all product

```
Select * from Products WHERE CompanyID = "id from previous query"
```

Comment: how about using join?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't know how/where to store Company.ID from first query to use it for second query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in the same database you can just join the two tables

```
SELECT
Company.Name, Products.Name, Products.PartNo, Products.IDSGroup
FROM
Company
LEFT JOIN Products
ON Company.ID = Products.CompanyID
WHERE
Company.Name LIKE "$userSearch%"
```